# cv::putText in IplImages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, mat, iplimage

When using the following syntax is for cv::Mat

```
cv::putText(...)
```

What about putting text into an IplImage? Is there a way to do so, without making changes / converting from Mat to IplImages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean "...without making changes / converting from IplImages to Mat" ?

What about [cvPutText(CvArr* img, const char* text, CvPoint org, const CvFont* font, CvScalar color)](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=cvputtext#void) ?